# C++ mangle names in dll and in using this dll project don't matched

Tags: c++, dll, libc++, dumpbin, demangler

I'm trying to use some lib and dll in my Visual C++ (2015, OS - Windows8x64) MFC Win32 project. This lib is old, from 2005. And in my project I recieve unresolved external symbol errors on some dll's functions calling. So I made a little dumpbin on the referenced dll and it turned out that the mangle names do not match. 
For example these functions. In *.h file:

1.

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CDcmPatientModule : public CDcmModule
{
public:
    DECLARE_SERIAL( CDcmPatientModule );
public:
    CString& PatientName();
......
}
```

and

2.

```
class  AFX_EXT_CLASS CDcmIOD : public CObject
{
    friend CDcmModule;
public:
    DECLARE_SERIAL( CDcmIOD );
    void Export( const CString& pathname );
    .....
};
```

1.
Mangle name in project

```
?PatientName@CDcmPatientModule@@QAEAAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@XZ
```

Mangle name in dll

```
?PatientName@CDcmPatientIdentificationModule@@QAEAAVCString@@XZ
```

demangle name in project (undname command) is:

```
public: class ATL:CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT > > & __thiscall CDcmPatientIdentificatioModule::PatientName(void)
```

demangle name in dll is:

```
public: class CString & __thiscall CDcmPatientIdentificatioModule::PatientName(void)
```

2.
Mangle name in project

```
?Export@CDcmIOD@@QAEXABV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z
```

Mangle name in dll

```
?Export@CDcmAttributeSet@@QAEXABVCString@@@Z
```

demangle name in project

```
public void __thiscall CDcmIOD::Export(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char>>>const &)
```

And demangle name in DLL

```
public: void __thiscall CDcmAttributeSet::Export(class CString const &)
```

So as you can see the difference is between "CString"
How to make these names matched??

Added #define USE_ADS_SHARED_LIB - nothing is changed
Adding __stdcall in function's declaration also didn't help.

Comment: Are you using two different classes called CString?

Comment: This dll is not mine, don't know what class is using there. I use standart mfc CString class, as I think.. how to check this?